# App Store export compliance

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, app-store

Does my app need an export compliance if it uses parse (now migrated to heroku + mongoDB)? I researched a bit and know that export compliance is not needed for parse. Just want to make sure, thanks!

Comment: If you already did the research and know it's not needed, why are you asking here?

Comment: the reason why i think export compliance is not needed is because a parser said so in a thread on parse. But that post is from 3 years ago so i'm not sure whether its still valid today and im also not sure if the migration changes anything

Comment: You are showing good sense by asking. Being a new developer does not absolve you of knowing the law. Parse shipped demo apps. Their attorneys should have told them to not offer any opinion on export compliance. Most people have not really connected the dots -- TLS v1.2 is export controlled encryption, my app uses TLS to connect to Parse's servers, ergo I use export controlled encryption and must obtain a license. You should consult your attorney.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use HTTPS:? I hope you've set up your Parse server to use https/TLS v1.2. Apple's ATS requires TLS v1.2+ these days. You should check with your attorney. I believe you need an export license. Apparently, once your company receives a commodity license, you do not need to reapply. But only your attorney can answer that authoritatively.

Comment: thanks for the reply! yes my parse server uses https, I am a new individual developer so i dont know much about the commodity license